# Is there a Roslyn Analyzer that detects newline preferences?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to ensure that

- there is always a blank line between methods
- there are never two or more blank lines in a row

Are there any Roslyn Analyzers that could handle such cases?

Comment: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1516.md https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1507.md

Comment: Thanks. I used SA1513 and SA1507, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 has some built-in functionality with [editorconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options).

There's also [StyleCop.Analyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.Analyzers).